# .htaccess rule: multiple domains to one ssl domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've tried around getting the following to work for 2 hours now.

I have multiple domains such as:
    Test.Xy.zz
    Test.Abc.de
    Test.mmm.mm

Now only Test.xy.zz got an ssl certificate and the application running on it is limited to it. Therfor I want all non-ssl requests - including test.xy.zz and all other domains to go to https://test.xy.zz

Hope someone can help.

**Possible solution:**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !test\.xy\.zz
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://test.xy.zz/$1 [QSA,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://test.xy.zz/$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^test.xy.zz$
 RewriteRule (.*) https://test.xy.zz$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I appreciate it.  However, https://test.mmm.mm would not be rewritten to the correct ssl url causing certification errors.

Comment: You said you wanted all NON-ssl requests redirected ;) But I'll add an answer for you... Note that if already connecting to SSL, the first connect to `https://test.mmm..` WILL produce certificate errors, as redirection takes place AFTER the SSL handshake. There is no way to circumvent that.

Comment: I noticed that. Was really late yesterday ;) Thanks for editing your answer. Fixed it myself as well :P (see question) - marking your answer as answer. Thanks again.