# .htaccess - Force use of single domain and SSL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, mod-rewrite

I have an SSL for www.example.com, and a bunch of alias domains (e.g. mydomain.co.uk, otherdomain.com etc. etc.) parked on the cPanel account.

What I want to do is force the use of https://www.example.com for all requests. Anything after the domain should be appended as it is (which is also rewritten for SEO friendly URLs later in .htaccess).

For example: -

```
http://example.com/page/2/
https://example.com/page/2/
http://www.otherdomain.com/page/2/
http://mydomain.co.uk/page/2/
```

should all become

```
https://www.example.com/page/2/
```

This almost works: -

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But can it be done in one go? Also, the above is appending the query string again to the URL for example: -

```
http://www.example.com/page/2/
```

is ending up as: -

```
https://www.example.com/page.php/2/?2/
```

The search engine friendly SEO part is: -

```
Options +SymlinksIfOwnerMatch +MultiViews
RewriteRule ^(.*).php/(.*) $1.php?$2
```

Which should remain unchanged.

IIRC, before I forced the SSL, the forcing of just www.example.com was working fine as: -

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%2://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess rule: multiple domains to one ssl domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212134/htaccess-rule-multiple-domains-to-one-ssl-domain)

Comment: Looks similar, but the answer by @starkeen below gives better (if not perfect) results. The answer(s) on the suggested duplicate don't actually work for me, perhaps due to the SEO friendly additions I have?

Comment: The rules are practically identical, and this is the most common type of question for this tag. You're just helping fill up SO with crap. Did you put the new code first, before all other rewriting occurs?

Comment: Yes, I put this first. Sorry for filling up SO with a few bytes of text, and sorry if you think it's crap, but I didn't have a solution to my problem despite trying various solutions found at SO, so posted the question in case any forthcoming answer might help me and others. Isn't that why we're here???

Comment: The purpose of SO is to be a useful reference for everyone to solve problems, not just *your* problem. Sadly it's filling up with "I couldn't find my exact solution and I didn't RTFM." questions. This makes it *harder* to find relevant solutions when your problem isn't common and it snowballs. [I doubt your problem has not been solved before.](https://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+%22mod+rewrite%22+intitle%3Ahttps+OR+intitle%3Assl+intitle%3Awww)

Comment: Thanks for your help again. Despite R'ing TFM, and trying many of the solutions from your helpful link (again), I'm still getting duplication in the query string (see my comment below, e.g. http://www.example.co.uk/section/20/ rewrites to https://www.example.com/section.php/20/?20/). But I can live with this as the correct page is still displayed, and the CMS I'm using adds canonical URLs so the incorrect URL isn't at risk of being indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

To force www and https in a single redirection, you can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R]
```

Comment: Thanks, I change the 2nd condition to

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com [NC]`

to force the example.com domain as well as the www. However I'm still getting end URLs like: -

https://www.example.com/page.php/2/?2/

with this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this version. It uses the original request sent by the browser so should be immune to other rewriting. If you still experience the extra junk, it's coming from somewhere else.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com [NC]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=your.dev.server [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^\S++\s++(\S++)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%1 [DPI,NE,L,R=301]
```

The extra, commented rule is in case you need to avoid this redirect on your development server.

Comment: Thanks @Walf. I have an environment variable (DEV_SERVER) set on my dev server and use <IfDefine !DEV_SERVER>...</IfDefine> in .htaccess to ignore anything that's not needed there. This latest version is giving the same results as others, so you must be correct in that it's coming from somewhere else. The CMS I use re-writes URLs in some cases with a 301 redirect (PHP) and it must be this, but as far as I can see the (.htaccess) rewritten URLs are just fine. The correct page shows, and the HTML contains canonical URLs, so I can live with this. Many thanks again for sticking with it!